# Is it legal to collect data on "Every Administration staffer, campaign staffer, bundler, lawyer who represented... " of Trump administration

Tags: united-states, politics, database

AOC tweeted:

> Is anyone archiving these Trump sycophants for when they try to
> downplay or deny their complicity in the future? I foresee decent
> probability of many deleted Tweets, writings, photos in the future

And some guy associated with https://www.trumpaccountability.net/ replied with(tweet is deleted/protected, but data is still in google search for term trumpaccproject ):

> Yes, we are.
>
> The Trump Accountability Project (@trumpaccproject)
>
> Every Administration staffer, campaign staffer, bundler, lawyer who
> represented them — everyone.

One one hand it is perfectly fine to share information, on other hand it could be seen as political intimidation/harrasment...

Are there any laws related to this?

For purposes of this question assume that everything they collect is true, aka no false informations are presented about the people investigated, since I presume there are anti libel laws.
Also I am only interested in legality of this, please keep political views out of this.

Comment: What law would making this *illegal*? One could argue that this is a violation of their privacy, but a "right to be forgotten" as it was enacted in the EU does not exist the same way in the US, and even in the EU collecting a political opponent's past statements and quoting them later would be allowed.

Comment: @o.m. I think that's exactly what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The right to gather information is a central component of First Amendment protection.